# How to store variables in PHP for use in different scripts?

Tags: php, html, mysql, variables, global-variables

I'm really new to programming in PHP so the problem I'm having may be an extremely simple one to solve but I cant find the solution online and I've tried a number of different methods myself so any help you can give me would be really appreciated.
The problem I'm having is that when a user logs in to the system I need their username to be stored in a variable which can be used when a different PHP script is called.
For instance, when the user first logs in to the system, the username they have entered is fetched using code similar to that seen below:

```
    $username = ($_POST['entered_username']);
    mysql_real_escape_string($username);
```

Where 'entered_username' is the name of the username input in the log in form within the HTML code. The problem I'm having is how to store the $username variable so it can be used in a different script. For instance when the user moves onto a page where he/she can see their own personal information which is stored in a MySQL database. Ideally I would like to use a SQL query such as the one below:

```
    $qry = ("select Username, Password, UserType from $table where Username = '".$username."'");
```

However this is not possible as the variable $username would not be defined in this script. So how can I store the $username variable in order to access it again via another PHP script.
Thanks in advance for all your help and apologies if any of the information I have provided is too vague.

Comment: use `session` variables

Comment: Look for `php sessions` or start at the manual: http://www.php.net/session_start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `$_SESSION` variable. It allows you to pass data between pages.

```
session_start();
$username = ($_POST['entered_username']);
mysql_real_escape_string($username);
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

then on any other page you can call it by using:

```
session_start();
$qry = ("select Username, Password, UserType from $table where Username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'");
```

Make sure that you call `session_start()` at the top of your page, before you have outputted any HTML to the page. Otherwise you will cause a headers error.

Answer (score 1):

Most simple solution: `SESSION` variables.

On your login page, add this code *at the top of the page*:

```
session_start();
```

then set your variables like this:

```
$_SESSION['var_1'] = $some_val;
$_SESSION['var_2'] = $some_other_val;
```

you can then access them on any other php page with the `session_start();` code on top.
Note however that this session data gets deleted when the user closes his/her browser. For more persistant, "long-lived" variables use `$_COOKIE` variables or store values in db and access the variables from there.

### Useful links

- [**How to set/delete cookies in PHP (from the Manual)**](https://www.php.net/setcookie).
- [**Security regarding sessions**](http://phpsec.org/projects/guide/4.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use $_SESSION variables.
When  a user logs in to your site store the variable in $_SESSION global variable.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['user'] = $/* user */;
```

In another php script you can set ;

```
session_start();
$user = $_SESSION['user'];
```

Comment: why do you have comments around user?

Comment: So they can use php code to set the variable as the user.